# Generic Interfaces and Type Parsing

Tags: c#, generics, collections, types, interface

I am trying to pass messages between several classes that communicate through interface. However, as I like to go as generic as possible, I ran into problems because the message type of incoming messages may be different from the outgoing type. I pasted some code to make it clearer.

The code below does not compile because the interface implementation passes a different type than the type of the blocking collection to which it is supposed to add incoming messages. I want to be able to send types potentially different from incoming types (incoming types obviously always match the type of the elements in the blocking collection). Can I somehow get around any sort of casting or parsing even if that means I need to redesign my interface or class?

I am still quite fresh when it comes to working with interfaces and struggled with recursions, stack overflow errors, and the like. So, if you have suggestions what I can improve design wise or just a quick fix then please help me to learn. Am very eager to understand how to implement a better pattern.

Thanks

```
public interface IClientMessaging
{
    void MessagePassing<U>(U message);
}

public class InProcessMessaging<T> : IClientMessaging
{
    private Dictionary<Type, List<IClientMessaging>> Subscriptions;
    public BlockingCollection<T> MessageBuffer;

    public InProcessMessaging(Dictionary<Type, List<IClientMessaging>> subscriptions)
    {
        //Setup Message Buffer
        MessageBuffer = new BlockingCollection<T>();

        //Subscribe
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (subscriptions.Keys.Contains(type))
        {
            subscriptions[type].Add(this);
        }
        else
        {
            subscriptions.Add(type, new List<IClientMessaging>());
            subscriptions[type].Add(this);
        }

        Subscriptions = subscriptions;
    }

    public void SendMessage<U>(U message)
    {
        //Send message to each subscribed Client
        List<IClientMessaging> typeSubscriptions = Subscriptions[typeof(U)];
        foreach (IClientMessaging subscriber in typeSubscriptions)
        {
            subscriber.MessagePassing<U>(message);
        } 
    }

    public T ReceiveMessage()
    {
        return MessageBuffer.Take();
    }

    public bool ReceiveMessage(out T item)
    {
        return MessageBuffer.TryTake(out item);
    }

    //Interface Implementation
    public void MessagePassing<U>(U message)
    {
        MessageBuffer.Add(message); //<-"Cannot convert from U to T" [this is because I want
                                    //to send messages of a different type than the receiving type]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `InProcessMessaging` both implement `IClientMessaging` and manage subscriber lists of `IClientMessaging`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand your goal here, but perhaps `MessagePassing<U>(U message)` should be `MessagePassing(U message)` and `interface IClientMessaging` should be `interface IClientMessaging<U>`.

Then `InProcessMessaging<T, U> : IClientMessaging<U>` - but I don't see why `InProcessMessaging` implements `IClientMessaging` AND manages subscriber lists of `IClientMessaging`.  Seems to me that one class would manage the subscribers and another IS a subscriber (`IClientMessaging`).

You say `U` and `T` are different types.  Well - are they related?  Is one wrapper for the other? Sounds like maybe `U` is either a wrapper for `T`, a generic class itself that contains the `T` but adds extra info.  In that case, `void MessagePassing<T>(Wrapper<T> message);`

UPDATES

Based on the comments so far ...

```
interface IClientMessage {}

interface IClientMessage<U> : IClientMessage { /* ... */ }
```

But rename those to:

```
interface IConsumer {} // (Or ISubscriber?)

interface IConsumer<TConsumed> : IConsumer{ /* ... */ }
```

and add:

```
interface IGenerator { }

interface IGenerator <TGenerated> : IGenerator { 
    event EventHandler<TGenerated> ItemGenerated; 
}
```

Then:

```
class Manager
{
    Dictionary<TConsumed, IConsumer> consumers = new ...

    /* Code for attaching ItemGenerated event handlers to clients */
}

class MyClient : IGenerator<string>, IConsumer<Foo>, IConsumer<Bar>
{
    event IGenerator<string>.ItemGenerated ...

    void IConsumer<Foo>.Consume(...) ...

    void IConsumer<Bar>.Consume(...) ...
}
```

Yes, this would use reflection to invoke `IConsumer<TConsumed>.Consume()`.  Or you can leave off the generics and just use `object` as your types.  Better yet, `IClientMessage` can have a `Consume(object message)` which in your implementation can ensure that `object` is a `TConsumed` before attempting to process it.

You could otherwise create direct client-to-client links through C# events, but you seem intent on a central dispatcher.  It is the central dispatchers need to keep track of these different and unbounded number of types that is either going to require reflection OR be unaware of the types being passed (as described in the previous paragraph)

You should look at [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) and the Observer pattern for ideas as well.

I removed my comments because it was getting too chatty.

Comment: I believe your idea does not get around reflection? I look for a solution that adheres to strong typing and I don't see how your answer addresses that. Please correct me if I am wrong. As described messages can be type safe passed to the blocking collections the only reason I ever thought about using interfaces was to hold all the clients/message recipients in one collection in order to pass certain message types to matching clients that implemented blocking collections that match such types. Under no circumstances do I want to give up strong typing.

Comment: No it does not.  Unless you don't like `is` and `as` either.  I think the "Better yet" part avoids reflection.

Comment: uosɐſ, thanks for the time you took and your ideas. I spent time to think and played with your ideas. I believe I may just setup a repository of blocking collections holding specific types in a static class and access those directly. I afford to do so because I never have more than one client adding to the same collection at the same time and never have more than one client consuming from one given blocking collection. Your solution looks elegant but it at the same time seems overly complicated just in order to solve the simple problem of wanting to address collections of different types.

Comment: ...the goal was point-to-point message passing of different message types. parsing/unboxing/reflection adds so much overhead that it defeats my purpose in wanting to pass several million messages per second. I admit I lack advanced skills in programming C# so maybe I miss ideas that may achieve what I want to do but I need to focus on a very low level, high throughput solution to adhere to my performance goals. Do you see any problems addressing public static blocking collections directly other than ending up with a very naive, trivial solution?

Comment: I don't see anything in here that would be described as parsing or unboxing.  Reflection, perhaps, but minimally.  If per channel you have one sender and one receiver, I would look at C# events and using the threadpool to process the event handlers asynchronously.

Comment: Also, and I hate to be so petty but it will be helpful for you in the long run - strive to be generous with your upvotes.  Your graciousness is good too but your upvotes are free for you to give out and I believe they encourage people to participate.  ;-)

Comment: If you're changing direction, you should probably start a new question once you've consolidated your thoughts on that new direction.

Comment: thanks for the hints (some of which I followed right away to show my appreciation ;-) I am still running performance tests to compare latency and throughput, interfaces is definitely a topic that is one of the more challenging ones to handle eloquently. I am still playing around with ideas, I like how you spit up generator and consumer parts.

Comment: uosɐſ, I wanted to thank you for the time you took to comment and for the code samples. They helped me a great deal and I really appreciate your efforts. I am a newbie here so I apologize for not knowing that I can also upvote comments not just answers. I ended up implementing interfaces for performance critical messaging and used buffered collections of type dynamic for others because it added some overhead in my performance runs. I learned a great deal so thanks again!!! I marked your answer as the one I was looking for because you essentially got me on the right path.

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  I love this site.